# Deleting my mail in Mac, but space is not cleared

Tags: mac, email, disk-space, macos, space

Today, I deleted alot of files in Mac Mail but it did not clear any space on my HD. It keeps saying Mail is using 5.36 GB, no matter how much I delete and empty my trash. I have rebooted several times. I'm using Macbook Air with Catalina.

Comment: Those are most likely time machine backups.  System Report -> Window -> Storage adminstration should clean them.

Comment: . @kelly where did you delete those files from ? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/390592/remove-attachments-from-sent-messages